# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 doesn't has Windows Driver option?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I tried to write a Universal Windows driver (UMDF 2) based on a template follow the intrustions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-umdf-driver-based-on-a-template) 
.

The problem is I can't see Windows Driver option in my VS 2015.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V3XZ.png)

Comment: To develop drivers, you need to use the Windows DDK, which comes with its own compiler, linker, and libraries.  Unfortunately, it doesn't com with an IDE, and builds are based on make files.

Comment: Yes. I have installed Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 10 in my computer.

Comment: You can configure VS to work with it, but it is a such a pain, almost no one does it.  Find a good editor, like vscode, or similar, and use make builds.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall and re-install my WDK 10 then the problem is fixed.